# Question about creating a UITextField programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two classes:

- RootViewController.h
- RootViewController.m

In my RootViewController.h

```
// in .h file 
UITextField* myTextField_;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* myTextField.
```

In my RootViewController.m

```
// in .m file
@synthesize myTextField = myTextField_

// in dealloc
[myTextField_ release]


// in viewDidLoad
UITextField* tf  = [[UITextField alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)];
[nameTextField_ = tf];
[tf release]
```

My question is, 
Does that create any memory leaks? Or will that crash? Are there better ways to create an instance of UITextField so I keep a reference to it? Perhaps

```
myTextField_ = [[UITextField alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)];
```

would that be sufficient?

Comment: Not sure why you have the textfield as a property and synthesize it. You want the textfield to be accesable from outside the class RootviewController? That sounds like a bad idea to me. Also, your code would still work fine without the property and synthesize lines.

Comment: interesting remark. the tutorials i've started out with property and synthesize all their stuff (maybe its bad? who knows). as for that i will probably make it private or so

Comment: Having textfield as a property is fine but if it is only used in the class move the property declaration into the .m file in a class extension.  ONly put items in the .h that you want to expose to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest way is to do this like this:

.h:

```
UITextField *myTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *myTextField;
```

.m

```
@synthesize myTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myTextField release];
}
```

You will have one instance which is allocated and released in most clean way and you will have reference to this textfield all the time.

Comment: This is the way to go, yet again, not sure about the property and synthesizing. If you want the text in the text field available you can either store that in a NSString that is a property (and synthesized)  or make a custom getter that gets it directly from the TextField

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will do:

```
myTextField_ = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)];
```

You can also use this:

```
self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)] autorelease];
```

(when using the property it will retain, when using directly the member `myTextField_` it won't (automatically) retain). Also `alloc` will set retainCount to 1 so it will eventually need to be released (in your case in `dealloc` method you can use either `[myTextField_ release];` or `self.myTextField=nil;`);

Not sure what this is (I believe it will show up some compile errors):
`[nameTextField_ = tf];`

Comment: `alloc` will *not* set the retain count to 1.   It only returns an object that must be `release`d which may be a *different* object than the one returned by the subsequent `init` (whereby `init` only guarantees that it effectively consumes one retain count and produces another retain count in the case where the object returned is different).

Comment: Not sure if that's true: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc

Comment: Documentation is wrong (filed <rdar://problem/10085249>).  There are lots of +alloc implementations that return singletons and/or other objects whose retain count is *not* 1.  (Thanks for pointing out the erroneous docs).

Answer (score 1):

You should not do `[tf release]` as you are accessing your variable directly.

If you access it via `self.` notation that it will be called `[tf retain]` and then you should release `tf`. So in your current version all is ok besides line where you are releasing.

Answer (score 1):

[nameTextField_ = tf];

---

change:

[self setMyTextField:tf]